# How can I paginate the results of GEOSEARCH?

Tags: redis

I am following the tutorial on https://redis.io/commands/geosearch/ and I have successfully migrated ~300k records (from existing pg database) into `testkey` (sorry for the unfortunate name, but I am testing it out!) key.

However, executing a query to return items with 5km results in 1000s of items. I'd like to limit the number of items to 10 at a time, and be able to load the next 10 using some sort of keyset pagination.

So, to limit the results I am using

```
GEOSEARCH testkey FROMLONLAT -122.2612767 37.7936847 BYRADIUS 5 km WITHDIST COUNT 10
```

How can I execute GEOSEARCH queries with pagination?

Some context: I have a postgres + postgis database with ~3m records. I have a service that fetches items within a radius and even with right indexes it is starting to get sluggish. For context, my other endpoints can handle 3-8k rps, while this one can barely handle 1500 (8ms average query exec time). I am exploring moving items into redis cache, either the entire payload or just IDs and run IN query (<1ms query time).

I am struggling to find any articles using google search.

Comment: You can use [GEOSEARCHSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/geosearchstore/) to store the result into a sorted set, then paginate that set with the regular [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange/) command (see example under the GEOSEARCHSTORE page) - would that work?

Comment: thank you! yes that seems like a good way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GEOSEARCHSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/geosearchstore/) to create a sorted set with the results from your search. You can then paginate this sorted set with [`ZRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrange/). This is shown as an example on the `GEOSEARCHSTORE` page:

```
redis> GEOSEARCHSTORE key2 Sicily FROMLONLAT 15 37 BYBOX 400 400 km ASC COUNT 3 STOREDIST
(integer) 3
redis> ZRANGE key2 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "Catania"
2) "56.441257870158204"
3) "Palermo"
4) "190.44242984775784"
5) "edge2"
6) "279.7403417843143"

redis>
```